# How to return the highest number only from a for loop

Tags: actionscript-3

I have written this function:

```
public function Main() {
        kickcount(24);
    }

    private function kickcount(kick:int){
        var kicknr:int = 0;
        for(var i:int = 0; i <= kick; i++){
            kicknr = kicknr + i;
            trace(kicknr);
        }
    }
```

The output is this:

```
0
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
55
66
78
91
105
120
136
153
171
190
210
231
253
276
300
```

I want to rewrite the function so that it will only outputs 300. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method of achieving the same output results is like this:

```
    public function Main() {
        kickcount(24);
    }

    private function kickcount(x:int){
        var formula = (x * (x / 2) + (x / 2));
        trace(formula);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the trace after the for loop.

```
private function kickcount(kick:int){
    var kicknr:int = 0;
    for(var i:int = 0; i <= kick; i++){
        kicknr = kicknr + i;
    }
    trace(kicknr);
}
```